# Can I retain part of a filename when using the gpg command and searching for a file with a wildcard?

Tags: bash

How do I retain part of a filename within the gpg command when choosing a file with a wildcard?

The filenames change daily/monthly, but I need the command to remain static.

before encryption:

```
FILENAME.1234
FILENAME.9876
```

after encryption:

```
FILENAME.1234.pgp
FILENAME.9876.pgp
```

command so far:

```
 gpg --batch --passphrase-fd 0 --output /usr/tmp/FILENAME*.pgp --encrypt -r "Some Quoted Text" --sign -u UserName /usr/tmp/FILENAME*
```

Is this possible to do from the command line, or do I need a for loop?

Answer (score 3):

`gpg` doesn't take multiple filenames as `--output` and that's what the shell fileglob is going to expand to.  So you'll have to "loop" or use `xargs` to run the command once per file.

I would use `find` and `xargs` with the null separator (`-print0`/`-0`) because I'm in the habit of writing whitespace-safe file name operations:

```
find /usr/tmp -iname 'FILENAME.*' -print0 | xargs -0 -I %  \
    gpg --batch \
    --passphrase-fd 0 --output %.pgp --encrypt \
    -r "Some Quoted Text" --sign -u UserName \
    %
```

Full disclosure: haven't tested that - too high of a burden to get gpg all setup for the test -  but it should be close.

Comment: +1. could also do it with just `-exec gpg ... {} \;`, without xargs.

Comment: It is saving the output as %.pgp

Comment: what version of xargs are you using?